# Dualbooting Problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot

I installed Windows 11 and Ubuntu 22.03 to my system. My system has 2 seperated disk, so I installed them into different disks. I firstly installed windows to my second disk, after that I installed Ubuntu to my first disk. When I boot my computer both options is available, but when I try to run Windows sometimes it does not boot and returning this error:

```
error: no such device E009-ED22.
error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found

Press any key to continue...
```

I couldnot figure out its pattern because sometimes It normally boots. Lastly If I try to boot on BIOS it boots everytime without problem.

What may cause this problem, and whats the solution of this?

Comment: You could try, open a yahoo search, copy/paste - error: file '/efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi' not found error . That search will lead you back to a askubuntu answer. I bet you need to turn secure boot off.

Comment: Is error from UEFI boot of Windows, or grub boot of Windows? Grub only boots working Windows. But that also means Windows cannot  be hibernated, fast startup on, nor encrypted with bitlocker as then Linux NTFS driver cannot see Windows.

Comment: grup boot does not work, but UEFI boot works perfectly. @oldfred

Comment: I already turned secure boot off @Nishnabe

Comment: If Windows boots ok direct from UEFI, then you may need to turn off fast start up and bitlocker. Fast start up sets hibernation flag preventing Linux NTFS driver from seeing the NTFS. If you force write when hibernated, the data is just lost when hibernation is restored. Note that Windows turns fast startup back on with Windows updates.

Comment: Are you saying it will boot from the BIOS ok, but when you try it from the GRUB it boots irregular? You will have to add more information to your question. As oldfred says above, when you shut windows down, hold the left shift key down when you shut down, and it will disable fast boot/hibernate the next time it boots. (you can disable hibernate/fast boot permanent also if you wanted)